# In a graph, how could the shortest path between two vertices be longer than the path between these two vertices in the graph’s minimum spanning tree?

Tags: tree

Since shortest path is already “shortest”, is it possible be longer than any other path in MST? I know the path between these two vertices usually longer than the shortest path between the two vertices, but could it be shorter?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for the original graph G’s shortest path between two vertices to be longer than the path between the same two vertices within the graph’s minimum spanning tree, or MST.

MST’s are trees or graphs that connect every vertex or node within the graph with the lowest sum of edge weights possible. This typically means that edges are removed from the graph in order to make the minimum spanning tree.

However, this means that the MST might include all of the edges that recreate the shortest path between the two vertices as it occurs in G. If the MST contains all of these edges, then the shortest path between the two vertices in the MST will be the same length as the shortest path between the two vertices in G.

Opposite to that, the MST might not include all of the edges that recreate G’s shortest path, meaning that the two vertices were connected to other vertices utilizing edges not present in G’s shortest path. This would then mean that the shortest path between the two vertices in the MST must always be larger (or equal to if there are multiple shortest paths in the original graph) than the shortest path in G.